# Setting a Unique Key for my Cards so that I can click a button and delete them in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to delete cards that I have added to my container. These cards have a number in the center of them that is randomly generated. I have managed to set a unique key to these cards but everytime the add card button is added and a new card appears, the numbers are randomly generated again, so they change. This ends up creating duplicate unique keys and the browser console throws an error.

I am then trying to use those unique keys to be able to click the red X at the top right of the card so that I can delete that card. But since I can't keep the unique keys 'unique', I have been unable to do this.

My random number generator.

```
  let getRandomNumber = function (min, max) {
    let getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
    return getRandom;
  };
```

The code for my cards.

```
  const MainCard = () => {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Button
          onClick={() => removeCard()}
          className="ui mini red basic icon button"
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: "0",
            right: "0",
          }}
        >
          <i
            className="red x icon"
            style={{
              position: "relative",
              top: "0",
              right: "0",
            }}
          ></i>
        </Button>
        <Card.Body>{getRandomNumber(0, 101)}</Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  };
```

The container where the cards are populated each time the "Add Card" button is pressed.

```
      <div className="card-container">
        {cards.map((cardNumber, index) => (
          <MainCard number={cardNumber} key={cardNumber.toString()} value={cardNumber} onRemove={() => removeCard(cardNumber)} />
        ))}
      </div>
```

Remove Card

```
  const removeCard = (cardIndex) => {
    // Create a new Array without the item that you are removing.
    const newCards = cards.filter((card, index) => index !== cardIndex);

    setCards(newCards);
  };
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've reviewed this article, https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html and feel I have a somewhat decent understanding of unique keys but I still can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

1. You really shouldn't use random numbers as React keys as there isn't really a guarantee of uniqueness. This is especially true since you are only generating 101 random values, so as soon as you have 102 cards you're guaranteed to have a duplicate.
2. You are not really generating state or anything else that persists *through* rerenders. You are generating your content on-the-fly.

## Solution

Since you want to add and remove cards "randomly" you need to store generated card data. You should also generate a unique id to go with the data that is being mapped.

1. Use an id generator to create unique ids that can be assigned to a card data element. I suggest something a little more robust, like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), but really anything the generates a unique, non-reapeating id is sufficient for this basic use-case.
2. Generate and store in component state the generated card data.
3. Pass the card element id to the delete handler to be used to filter cards by id.
4. Use the card element id as the React key when mapping cards.

Code

```
const generateId = (seed = 0) => () => seed++;

const getRandomNumber = function (min, max) {
  let getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
  return getRandom;
};

const MainCard = ({ number, onRemove }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {number}
      <button onClick={onRemove} className="ui mini red basic icon button">
        <i
          className="red x icon"
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            top: "0",
            right: "0"
          }}
        >
          x
        </i>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const addCard = () => {
    setCards((cards) => [
      ...cards,
      {
        id: generateId(),
        number: getRandomNumber(0, 101)
      }
    ]);
  };

  const removeCard = (id) => {
    setCards((cards) => cards.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <button type="button" onClick={addCard}>
        Add
      </button>

      <div className="card-container">
        {cards.map((cardNumber, index) => (
          <MainCard
            number={cardNumber.number}
            key={cardNumber.id}
            onRemove={() => removeCard(cardNumber.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit setting-a-unique-key-for-my-cards-so-that-i-can-click-a-button-and-delete-them-i]

***Note:** I did take some liberties with removing your custom components in rendering this simple example. It just needed to render a number value and delete button.*

Comment: Yeah this is great. It removed styling and what not and made a few other things not work but I fixed those and it's working perfectly. I'll just add the styling back and it's what I was trying to do exactly. Do you have any documentation on this? Where's the best place for me to understand exactly what's going on here? I guess I should familiarize myself more with useState and state. Seems like that's the main portion of this.

Comment: @KenanBjelosevic Great! Glad it works well for your use-case. Honestly, just spending the time to read and understand the official React docs should be sufficient. I think for React it is most important to understand the component lifecycle, not so much what state is, but when and how it updates, and what effects the lifecycle. When you really understand lifecycle then state updates and react hooks will become trivial to use. Good luck and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was passing cardNumber instead of index in the key={}. I changed it over to index and the keys where unique. I still need to figure out how to delete now so that's the next step.